# How google api key for map v2 should I use for?

Tags: android, api-key

I saw in the site of the console developer than there are two ways to obtain an api key: one for debug and one for release. How could I use for? If I use the release key, should I use debug? And if I want to sell my application out of google play, must I pay 25$ for google?
Thank you for answers

Answer (score 0):

Debug code is (as name says) for debugging and overall development process. If you want to post your app into Google Play you would have to obtain a release key. 
And yes, you have to pay 25 to get access to GPlay store.

Comment: But if I want to sell this application without play store?